# Disabling authorisation or allow any snmp community string in snmp input trap plugin

Tags: logstash, snmp

SNMP input trap plugin assumes community string to be present or if we don't provide it takes "public" by default.
As per the docs, community string can be array also.

I want to support any community string. SNMP input trap plugin doesn't support disabling authorization also. How can I make it work for any community string

```
snmptrap {
    port => 10162
    community => "my-community-string"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those how are struck at this issue, I find the solution

**Problem**

In Snmp input trap plugin its mandatory to pass a string or an array as an community string or else "public" is taken as default, you can look at the github code for the same [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-snmptrap/blob/master/lib/logstash/inputs/snmptrap.rb)

**Solution**

I change the plugin code itself to make it work, just replace this in code and you SNMP community string will have no restriction.

line no: 70

```
    traplistener_opts = {:Port => @port, :Community => @community, :Host => @host}
```

replace it with

```
    traplistener_opts = {:Port => @port, :Host => @host}
```